# Exp-resso Store Shipping Address Not showing

Tags: expresso-store

[image]When the user puts in the 'shipping details' (checkout2) because it's different than the billing address the address does  NOT SHOW on the next page (Confirm Order page:  checkout3)  as part of the checkout process. It says 'Same as 'Billing Details' when it should show the shipping address, because its different that the billing address. It also does NOT SHOW on the order page.

However, the shipping information is being captured in the form. If the Shipping Address is different that the Billing Address it will show up on the Confirmation email, the system sends out to the buyer, and it's available in the admin back end via the order report.

I am not using a shipping module, its all flat shipping.  I have the lastest version of Exp-resso Store, and I am using EE 2.11.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this. What does the conditional on your payment page look like? Was this after an upgrade?

```
{if shipping_same_as_billing == 1}
   Same as Billing Details
{if:else}
   Shipping address
{/if}
```

We had to change the original {if shipping_same_as_billing} conditional to have the '== 1' to fix the problem.